# Cakephp 3 authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp, forms-authentication, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm working with Cakephp3 and I got problem with Auth system.

Here's my code in UsersController:

```
public function login()
            {
                    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                            if ($user) {
                                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                            }
                            $this->Flash->error('Invalid username or password, try again');
                        }
                }
```

In AppController:

```
    public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

         $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
'authenticate' => [
    'Form' => [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password'
        ]
    ]
]]);

}
```

in login.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->button('log in');
echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

and I've created a table called users which  has fields: Full texts 
id
first_name
last_name
username
password
created
modified

and I have sample user with the Username= hosein , password:123 but when I put in the data that does not work and says invalid username of password.

really why?!

Comment: Have you done any of the basic checks that are suggested in other questions about login problems that can be found here on SO? Checked the column type/length, ensured that the passwords are really stored hashed, debugged the queries that are being issued (Do they find anything at all? If there's actually something being found, what exactly is it, does it match the value in the DB?), ensured that hashes are generally being stored correctly when creating a new user, etc...

Comment: Did you specify any password hashing function within User entity? Or are raw passwords being stored in your database?

Comment: those are not hashed....but I just added a hashed one manually in database and ran it but didn't work again.

Comment: ndm: query and things are working properly...I've tested all needed...I've added users to table by query and retrieved some data to test if it's connted to the table. and that was all well.

Comment: What does "_added a hashed one manually_" and "_added users to table by query" mean? How did you create the hash? How did you create the query?

Comment: ps, you need to add an @ in front of the username in order to tag a user in a comment, like @hoseinbarzegaran.

Comment: @ndm I hashed a password via a hashing site then I created user with PhpAdmin and inserted the hashed password in that....and second one I've tested the Auth create user queries and that part worked , I was able to create users with that but login does not work.

Comment: Using external services for hashing won't work, as they do not use your application salt. Please read **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords** and **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html** and do it that way.

Comment: Yup!....that was right , problem was with hashing ...It really teased me. I shouldn't have inserted some sample users with PhpAdmin and should done that with queries and with hashing ... thank you lot ndm.